# Wordpress: Can't see custom field after the Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields

I have created a loop to show some products on my wordpress site and they seem to be working fine they reel out the products however if I place one of custom fields after the loop it doesn't show. I know its not an issue with the custom field itself as it works fine if I put it above the loop. Does anyone know where I could be going wrong?

Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/SVxYK0XP

Thanks

Comment: Please add relevant code samples to the question, rather than linking to a pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setup_postdata()` within your loops, therefore overwriting the `$post` object.
When you are calling `the_field('monoblock_valves_text');` after the foreach loop, it's trying to get that custom field out of the last post of the loop, while it clearly needs to get it from the actual post/page showing.

You need to store the old $post object before the loop, and restore it after the loop, as such:

```
$old_post = $post;
foreach($products_mono_posts as $post):
  setup_postdata($post);
  // Rest of code
endforeach;
$post = $old_post;
setup_postdata($post);

the_field('blahblahblah');
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Just make sure to always follow this pattern when using setup_postdata() to avoid future problems.